# Migrar BD SQL Server a Oracle. Tablas vacias

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migration, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy siguiendo los pasos de la página de Oracle para migrar de SQL Server a Oracle usando el asistente de SQL Developer online. Estoy siguiendo los mismos pasos y la migración finaliza correctamente, pero las tablas que me ha creado están vacías.

Creo que mi problema es que estoy mirando el esquema equivocado. Cuando finaliza la migración el nuevo esquema que he creado para la migración "migration_repo" y no tiene datos. Este esquema se crea como soporte para la migración y tiene sentido que no tenga datos, pero entonces, ¿Que esquema es el que contendrá los datos? He probado a conectarme como SYS en la bd de Oracle y hago un `select count(*)` de las tablas tampoco tienen datos.

Revisando detenenidamente el video de Oracle veo que al finalizar la migración se conecta con unos nuevos usuarios que deberían haberse creado, pues bien, en mi caso esos usuarios no se crean o no se la contraseña de ellos. Esta es la parte del migration log donde crea los usuarios:

```
SQL> CREATE USER demohorazon IDENTIFIED BY &&demohorazon_password PASSWORD EXPIRE ACCOUNT LOCK /* DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP */;

old:CREATE USER demohorazon IDENTIFIED BY &&demohorazon_password PASSWORD EXPIRE ACCOUNT LOCK /* DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP */

new:CREATE USER demohorazon IDENTIFIED BY "#RiYOpmrSiWydn1q" PASSWORD EXPIRE ACCOUNT LOCK /* DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP */

SQL> GRANT CREATE SESSION, RESOURCE, CREATE VIEW, CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW, CREATE SYNONYM, UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO demohorazon;

SQL>
```

Intento conectar con el usuario **demohorazon** y esa la pass **"#RiYOpmrSiWydn1q"** y no puedo

Gracias

Comment: He comprobado como sys que el usuario demohorazon no se ha creado, a mi entender debería haberse creado. ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido solucionar el problema. Para ello he ejecutado una migración offline y he ejecutado el script de creación de objetos yo mismo a mano desde un SQL Develper. Una vez ejecutado el script a mano he podido conectar con el nuevo usuario creado,

En este video se explica como realizar la migracion offline paso a paso: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDiY62YgL2Q

No he conseguido saber el motivo por el cual la migración online no funcionaba cuando decía que migración terminada con exito.

Saludos!

Comment: estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo que tu realizaste ya que tengo el mismo error, mis datos de la bd no aparecen, cheque el video que dejaste pero me queda la duda de donde sale el tipo de archivo ocp, ¿tú de donde lo generaste?
De antemano muchas gracias